# When does the BackGroundWork RunWorkerCompleted event execute?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am confused about the `BackGroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted` event execution timing. 
This is my test code

```
private string hellow="hello";        
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool createAndRunWorkResult = CreateAndRunWork();
    if (createAndRunWorkResult)
    {
        //Do something that need wait RunBackGroundWorkerCompleted execute here.
        //MessageBox.Show(hello);
    }
}

private bool CreateAndRunWork()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    return true;
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Nothing here;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    hello="aloha";
}
```

My design workflow is to click the button1 and then do something after RunWorkerCompleted has executed.

But RunWorkerCompleted seems to be located on the bottom of the method stack. In other words: I'm getting `createAndRunWorkResult` before `RunWorkerCompleted` executes. What confuses me is if I uncomment `MessageBox.Show(hello)` in button1_Click, the `MessageBox.Show(hello)` will wait until `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` has executed. But, I still get a "hello" messagebox rather than "aloha".

I guess all UI operation will be located below the `RunWorkerCompleted` at the method stack.

However, I'm not sure if my assumption is correct and if there is a way to force do something only after `RunWorkerCompleted` has been executed?

Comment: Whatever you want to run "after" `RunWorkerCompleted` is the code you should be writing inside the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. That's exactly the place for you to put code that should run when the background job has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is, that a backgroudnworker is another thread that you can't wait for.
The backgroundworker is telling you when it's finished its work.
so your code should look like this

```
private string hellow="hello";        
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool createAndRunWorkResult = CreateAndRunWork();       
}

private bool CreateAndRunWork()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    return true;
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Nothing here;
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    hellow="aloha";
        //Do something that need wait RunBackGroundWorkerCompleted execute here.
        //MessageBox.Show(hellow);
}
```

I recommend reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28v=vs.120%29.aspx
 about threading

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundWorker object is designed to simply run a function on a different thread and then call an event on your UI thread when it's complete, So in your code you should call function which you want to run after RunWorkerCompleted.

There are 3 Steps:

1. Create a BackgroundWorker object.
2. Tell the BackgroundWorker object what task to run on the background thread (the DoWork function).
3. **Tell it what function to run on the UI thread when the work is complete (the RunWorkerCompleted function)**.

If you write function call in your code

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Test();//This is the code which in your case you want to run
        }
 void Test()
        {
            hello = "Hola";
            MessageBox.Show(hello);
        }
```

you will get HOLA message this is due to step 3 mentioned above. Hope this helps